# How to minimize linq queries and increase the performance

Tags: c#

```
var Table = new List();

var partlist = Table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Column1")) &&
            row.Field<string>("Column1").Equals(variableName1) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Column2")) &&
            row.Field<string>("Column2").Equals(variableName2))
            return true;
        return false;
    })
    .Select(row =>
    {
        return new
        {
            PartNumber = row.Field<string>("HardwareType"),
            Number = row.Field<string>("HardwareSerialNo")
        };
    })
    .Distinct();

var distinctParts =
    partlist
        .Select(part => { return part.PartNumber; })
        .Distinct();

foreach (var distinctPart in distinctParts)
{
    var list = partlist.Where(part =>
    {
        if (part.PartNumber.Equals(distinctPart))
            return true;
        return false;
    })
    .Select(part => { return part.Number; })
    .Distinct();

    int quantity = list.Count();
    hwList[distinctPart] = quantity;
}
```

The above code is working fine but its taking very long to execute. Is there any way to minimize the code and increase the performance.
Please help me out

Comment: Are you able to identify if there is a particular part that is executing slowly?

Comment: How did you find out linq degrades the performance?

Comment: I suggest caching the partlist on a in-memory list and keeping it synchronized with the DB with the repository pattern - Obviously, i don't know how possible it is for you to do that as it may take too much memory but it could boost your performance a lot.

Comment: The foreach statement is taking is much time. and i have one more doubt is it best way to use return true/false in the linq query ??

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is right, LINQ should not slow you down a lot as it is just sort of a wrapper over a SQL-generator

Comment: can you show me the example the way you suggested.

Comment: @user2862430 Just declare a list of the datatype for partlist and wrap all your db access in something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx where the repository prefers to access the in-memory cache instead of going to the DB directly

Comment: Actually, for each iteration in the foreach you make a hit to the database due to lazy loading. Turn of lazy loading for Number or select it from the first query

Comment: @Machinarius That is not the only thing LINQ is for...

Comment: i did not say that linq degrades the performance.. but we can minimize the above code but i am unable to do that..

Comment: Why are you wrapping an if statement that returns true else false around a boolean statement?

Comment: @Machinarius in the above, LINQ has nothing whatsoever to do with SQL

Comment: @MarcGravell I may of misunderstood the problem at hand then

Comment: Actually I am new to linq... i have to modify the above code please help me out

Comment: Well, starting with `DataTable` is not a promising start... frankly, I'd just leave this data in a RDBMS such as SQL Server, with indexing on the appropriate columns, and fetch it as needed. However, you could also index it in memory with a dictionary or similar. But right now: you are just looping over the rows one by one - yes, that will be slower than just about every other option out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not using the correct data type. For every entry in `distinctParts` it needs to iterate `partlist`. And that is a huge problem, because `partlist` defines *a query* and not the *result* of a query. In other words, for each iteration of the `foreach` loop, the `partlist` *query* is executed, executing all the code you defined for it:

1. Extracting the data from the rows
2. Creating new instances of the anonymous type
3. Removing the duplicate entries.

This is due to the deferred nature of LINQ queries.

I would go about this problem by extracting a dictionary from `partlist` that directly contains the data you need. This would execute the `partlist` query exactly once:

```
var parts = partlist.GroupBy(x => x.PartNumber)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                                  x => x.Select(y => y.Number)
                                        .Distinct().Count()));

foreach (var kvp in parts)
    hwList[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
```

Please note: I additionally removed the need for `distinctParts` with this.
This should be a lot faster.

Comment: can we copy parts into hwList dictionary without using foreach.. so that we can save little time

Comment: @user2862430: That depends on what `hwList` is for a data type. But you need to copy the data somehow, so some loop most likely is involved somewhere, so you won't save much time. You should now concentrate on what still takes too much time. And find that out by using a Profiler, not by guessing.

Comment: is it best way to use if conditions and return true/false statements in linq...??

Comment: @user2862430: No. You usually would simply use the condition directly: `Where(row =>
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Column1")) &&
            row.Field<string>("Column1").Equals(variableName1) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Column2")) &&
            row.Field<string>("Column2").Equals(variableName2)
    )`

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract out some of your filtering but otherwise I don't see places to enhance:

```
function bool IsMatch(row, column, match)
{
    var value = row.Field<string>(column);
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Equals(match);
}
```

which only really makes it more readable:

```
.Where(row => {
    return IsMatch(row, "Column1", variableName1) && 
           IsMatch(row, "Column2", variableName2);
 })
```

---

similar thing goes with your anonymous object. If you create a light little class you can abstract the implementation to the constructor:

```
public class PartModel
{
    public PartModel(TableRow row)
    {
        PartNumber = row.Field<string>("HardwareType");
        Number = row.Field<string> ("HardwareSerialNo");
    }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

which simplifies that to:

```
.Select(row => { return new PartModel(row) }; })
```